# Integrating Google Earth 3D globe in website

Tags: google-maps, google-earth, google-earth-api

I want to integrate a 3D globe like Google Earth in my website.

[image]

Is there any API or plugin available to integrate Google Earth in website?

I searched a lot for API but did not find any useful links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Google Earth API has been deprecated.
Depending on what you want it for, maybe some of these will help:

https://miniature.earth/
http://www.webglearth.com/
https://www.openglobus.org/
https://github.com/NASAWorldWind/WebWorldWind

Or any of these:
https://npm.io/search/keyword:globe

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i was using webglearth but getting this error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' api.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: WE is not defined at initialize (index-new.html:7) on some of the systems` can you please let me know the issue